# Binding Azure App managed SSL to custom domains throgh REST API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, cname, azure-custom-domain

Hi I have a PHP application installed in the Azure web app, in that application users can add there own domain as cname alias custom domains through submission of a form which already implemented, what I need is the option to bind Azure App managed SSL certificate to that custom domain so the customers can access the website in https, I am looking for a REST API for this functionality is it possible to automate this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've listed below the REST APIs you can use:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/createorupdate
  to create the app service certificate.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/domains/createorupdate
  to create the domain.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdatedomainownershipidentifier
  to assign the domain to the app service.

Comment: Thanks, I used the first API to generate a SSL thumbprint and  used that thumbprint in API listed below thread and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52835041/add-ssl-bindings-custom-domain-in-dynamically-created-web-app-service